# Receiving unexpected return value. Having problems with pointers in C

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, terminal, crash

I am learning the use of pointers, but for some reason my code makes the terminal give an unexpected return value. There is no warning shown in the log, thus I am unsure what's causing the problem. Any help is highly appreciated!
My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int findArraySum(int *pArr, int ArrSize)
{
    int i,sum=0;
    for(i=0;i<ArrSize;i++)
    {
        sum+=pArr[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
int main()
{
    int arraySize,i;
    printf("Size of array: ");
    scanf("%d",arraySize);
    int array[arraySize];
    for(i=0;i<arraySize;i++)
    {
        printf("Element [%d]: ",i+1);
        scanf("%d",array[i]);
    }
    printf("Sum of array: %d",findArraySum(array,arraySize));
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried using

```
//more code

int findArraySum(int *pArr, int *pArrSize)
{
    int i,sum=0;
    for(i=0;i<pArrSize;i++)

//more code
```

but to no avail, and I also received warning messages for making a pointer from an integer without a cast and for comparing pointer to integer.

Comment: `scanf("%d",array[i]);` should be `scanf("%d",&array[i]);`

Comment: or `scanf("%d", array + i);`

Comment: @EugeneSh. No, there's no good reason for anyone to write it like that.

Comment: @Barmar I'd say it is your opinion :) But it is cleaner from the "weird" typographical symbols and some might consider it more readable.

Comment: Thank you very much for both of you, didn't realize I missed the `&` sign. It's working fine now.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I'd say it's not idiomatic, it's not the way most C programmers code array indexing.

Comment: @Barmar, But it's not array indexing that's needed here -- we're not trying to access any of the elements -- it's pointer arithmetic. And it's very much idiomatic to use `array + i` for pointer arithmetic (I'm not saying `&array[i]` is bad, just that `array + i` isn't bad. I use the latter.)

Comment: @ikegami My point is that we always use `&place` in scanf (except when reading strings), and it's most natural to use the same syntax when the place is an array element.

Comment: Sure, we always use `f(&var)` to pass the address of non-array variables. (We tend to prefer using `f(var)` for array variables.) But that's not what we want to do there, so we can't use `&var` here. We don't want to pass the address of a var, but the address of an array element. And there are two idiomatic ways of writing that.